# Android Picasso make manual cache

Tags: android, picasso

I made an app that uploads an image to server, then loads it according certain URL. Question, if I know the exact URL of that image before upload, is possible to cache it without doing a new request to get it?

Answer (score 0):

First create a new class to get your own singleton picasso object

```
import android.content.Context;
import com.squareup.picasso.Downloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PicassoCache {

    /**
     * Static Picasso Instance
     */
    private static Picasso picassoInstance = null;

    /**
     * PicassoCache Constructor
     *
     * @param context application Context
     */
    private PicassoCache (Context context) {

        Downloader downloader   = new OkHttpDownloader(context, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(context);
            builder.downloader(downloader);

        picassoInstance = builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Get Singleton Picasso Instance
     *
     * @param context application Context
     * @return Picasso instance
     */
    public static Picasso getPicassoInstance (Context context) {

        if (picassoInstance == null) {

            new PicassoCache(context);
            return picassoInstance;
        }

        return picassoInstance;
    }

}
```

use your own singleton picasso object Instead of Picasso.With()

```
PicassoCache.getPicassoInstance(getContext()).load(imagePath).into(imageView)
```

answer for third question : you do not need any disk permissions for disk Cache operations